# Why is it stated that SQL Null type is not supported in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

In current version of PHP documentation it is expressed :

> No support for nulls. There is no support for SQL NULL type. It is not legal to assign PHP NULL to a data object property and the Relational DAS will not write that back as a NULL to the database. If nulls are found in the database on a query, the property will remain unset.

We know that it is possible to handle the `NULL` in parsed sql string like below :

```
 $myVar = NULL; 
 $query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES (‘an_id’ , ’$myVar’)” ;// obviously not working
 $query = “INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (‘an_id’, NULLIF('$myVar',''))”; // it works!
```

Why PHP core developers are reluctant to implement SQL null type in SDO-DAS?

What kind of problems it could possibly create?

Comment: It is not working because you are quoting NULL!

Comment: @MarkusZeller I corrected the code. Could you explain to me what does the above documentation quote want to tell?

Comment: If you cast a NULL to a string, you will get "" which is an empty string. Using the double quotes forces all variables to either be casted as a string or if it is a object, the magic function __toString is called. Please have look at my answer below. I've added an example for your needs.

Comment: So what does it mean : “There is no support for SQL null type”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PDO you can use NULL values from PHP.

```
$sth = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `mytable` SET `thenullcolumn`=?");
$sth->execute([null]);
```

In your case it is not working, because you are quoting the NULL. You may do this:

```
$myVar = empty($myVar) ? 'NULL' : "'$myVar'";
$query = "INSERT INTO myTable (id, name) VALUES (‘an_id’ , {$myVar})”;
```

Be aware, that is no good idea, because it may cause SQL Injections when not escaping. PDO is the most elegant and secure way IMHO.

Comment: Well, I havn’t been used PDO, but It is look like that it is much more convenient to use SDO-DAS and managing Null values with ‘NULLIF’ rather than PDO. The question that I am asking is why we can not enclose a NULL value in our sql statement?

Comment: Because if you write "NULL" you have a string. If you write NULL (without quotes) it is parsed as NULL by the Database.